# Is this empty-string check redundant?

Tags: java, android, string

In Android's `frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/policy/PhoneWindowManager.java` there is the clause:

```
    //if device type is tablet force enable NavigationBar and forbid NavigationBar move
    String deviceType = SystemProperties.get("sys.device.type");
    if (! "".equals(deviceType) && deviceType.equals("tablet")) {
        mNavigationBarCanMove = false;
        mHasNavigationBar = true;
    }
```

Is `! "".equals(deviceType) &&` entirely redundant, or is there some sense to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `if (! "".equals(deviceType) && deviceType.equals("tablet"))` is bad for several reasons:

1. `"".equals(deviceType)` is value free in this instance.
2. `deviceType.equals("tablet")` is a careless way to compare a String variable to a constant.
3. The use of the `!` can be confusing (which has higher precidence: ! or &&?) to soft java programmers.

Replace the statement with this:

```
if ("tablet".equals(deviceType))
```

This is better because it will not throw a NullPointerException when deviceType is null.

Note: The suggested use of TextUtils is also redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is redundant in this case because second clause involves the first one (if `deviceType` is not null), so you can simplified doing the following:

```
//Use constant string to perform comparison to avoid possible NPE
if("tablet".equals(deviceType)) {}
```

Comment: "Could be redundant..." - Thanks, but I was asking because I *thought* it was redundant, but wanted confirmation.  Why would I want `TextUtils.isEmpty` if `"".equals(deviceType)` is redundant?